# How to describe having the same amount of advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am writing a discussion paper and am taking a neutral position in the argument. In other words, there are the same amount of ideas for and against the topic. How can I express my disposition in decent formal words?

Comment: Can you share the remaining sentence?

Comment: Same number as advantage is countable. You may be better using a word like evidence where you can use amount.

Comment: Why are you assuming that one argument for has less weight than two arguments against? What if the single argument for is twice as strong as each of the two against? I'm just curious why you are equating neutrality with something purely quantitative. Are you looking for a numerical statement—or something more qualitative? And if you're taking a neutral position, why not just say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disinterested. 
The original meaning was as a Judge, without bias. You can frame your neutral position by saying you are presenting the evidence impartially, in a disinterested manner leaving the reader to weigh the evidence for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments for and against have equal footing or weight.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not taking the neutral position on purpose (so as not to seem biased), but rather you have strong feelings for **and** against the argument, to the point you can't decide which is better, you could be described as 'ambivalent'

This is when the choice becomes really difficult because there are really good arguments either way. These conflict your position, so that you might end up in the middle unable to choose.

[Ambivalent](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ambivalent)